# How to create image with 2 images ffmpeg

Tags: image, ffmpeg, subprocess, pipe

I want create with 2 or more images a unique image combining all images that i pass as parameter. I start proving with 2 parameters.

```
    firstpart = "/home/princebot/mazos/cartas/CannonCard.png"
    secondpart = "/home/princebot/mazos/cartas/FireballCard.png"
    a = subprocess.Popen(["ffmpeg","-i", firstpart, "-filter_complex", "scale=120:-1,","-i", secondpart, "-filter_complex","hstack" , "output.png"],stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
    a.communicate()[0].decode('utf-8')
```

and the combine image dont create.

Comment: Your question is very unclear. What do you start with and what do you expect to get as a result?

Comment: I want to create an image combining two images

Comment: One on the left and one on the right? One above and one below? The second composited over the first? The difference? The mean? The product?

Comment: i want create one image conbininbg 2 images first image on the right and the second image on the left

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your scale will output the appropriate size use:

```
a = subprocess.Popen(["ffmpeg","-i", firstpart, "-i", secondpart, "-filter_complex","[0]scale=120:-1[s];[s][1]hstack" , "output.png"],stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
```